# Does Speech-to-Text supports voice commands?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-cloud-speech

I am using Google Speech-To-Text for audio stream recognition. Is there a way to recognize voice commands for text editing like in Google Docs? For example, the response will indicate that it recognized command.

Comment: The Speech to text API does just that ... it converts speech to text.   If you supply audio to the API, it will return a text representation.  If you need further logic, you are responsible for that by (for example) using text to speech API to generate an audio response.   You might also want to look into Google's DialogFlow product for command processing.

Comment: Thank you! Reference to DialogFlow was helpful